# What is the best way to check if the currently selected option in a dropdown list is the last one?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a drop-down list and I've bound a change event handler to it. Whenever the user selects a new option, I want to know if it is the last option of the list.

Annoyingly, the relevant condition in the snippet below always returns true, no matter which option has been selected:

```
        sel.change(function() {
            //this always returns true!
            if(jQuery('#' + this.id + ' option').is(':last')) {
                alert('hello I am the last option');
                inputDiv.show();
                inputDiv.find("input").attr('disabled',false);
            } else {
                inputDiv.hide();
                inputDiv.find("input").attr('disabled',true);
            }
        });
```

Even if I do this, the result is the same:

```
if(jQuery('#' + this.id + ' option:selected').is(':last')) {
...
```

What am I doing wrong? And if you know, why do those tests both evaluate to true?

EDIT: Found the solution:

```
if(jQuery('#' + this.id + ' option:last').is(':selected')) {
...
}
```

Does anyone knows a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you have a solution to your own question you can add it as an answer not an edit to the question. Also, non-jquery option by porneL may be slightly faster.

Comment: +1 for descriptive question title

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look, no bloat!

```
 sel.selectedIndex == sel.length-1
```

That's [W3C standard solution](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980).

Comment: I admit, that is better. Thanks.

Comment: True, that doesn't look "jQuerish", but this method is so simple, that it doesn't need any convenience wrapper.

Answer (score 13):

Hey, here is another one... and it is "jQuerish" :)

```
$("select option:last").is(":selected")
```